# How to run java test files using Appium for android?

Tags: java, android, appium

I'm very new for Appium. I have configured all my Win-7(64 bit) machine using this [blog](http://automatium.blogspot.in/2013/08/appium-android-example-program-for.html) i.e Appium for windows, node.js and Android SDK with API level 17, emulator etc.

I found many java files on git-hub also in this [blog](http://automatium.blogspot.in/2013/08/appium-android-example-program-for.html)  also 
but How to run this java files I don't have idea.

If anybody guide me step wise will be very helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the java test file using following command:

`mvn -Dtest=com.saucelabs.appium.SimpleTest test`

Note: You need to open terminal -> navigate to project directory --> execute the above command.

Refer to this link: [Run Java Test File](https://github.com/appium/appium/tree/master/sample-code/examples/java/testng)

Answer (score 0):

For command line execution you can integrate your automation test with build tools.

Like Ant, Maven, Gradle. it can help you to execute and build automation test, also you can easily integrate with CI tools with the help of these.